# How to publish my Asp.Net MVC 4 app in lan?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, macos, iis, publish

I spent hours and hours reading all other Stackoverflow answers and none of them works.
Actually, I just finished my app, and I want to publish it on my lan from my machine.

Here are the steps I performed:

I went to VS2012 and clicked on publish my app. I went through all those steps.

It created a directory in "C:\inetpub\wwwroot".

After that, I went to the website in IIS Manager and clicked on edit bindings. I set localhost in hostname and 80 in port, and it works on my machine. After that I went to my firewall, and enabled World Wide Web Services (HTTP) in DOMAIN.

Then I executed a command in cmd:

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://localhost:80/ user=everyone
```

By the way, I'm running this on my parallels win7 64bits. Then I went to my OS X, and I type my win7 ip address and the port:

```
http://192.168.1.11:80/
```

It gives me this error.

> Not Found
>
> HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.

**I really need a step by step answer to how I can publish my website on my lan!! Thanks in advance.**

Comment: Do you have an empty host binding for the IP of your machine on this site? i.e Type,HostName,Port,IP,Binding Info;http,*blank*,80,192.168.1.11,*blank*

Comment: No, i have on my binding
Hostname:localhost
Port:80
IP:*

Comment: Try removing the hostname reference from the binding, if IIS complains that the binding already exists in another site, set the IP address as well.

Comment: Make a common folder shared in LAN 
and Publish your project in that folder.